Read CSV with missing/incomplete headers in Pyspark
I have a  CSV file with first row like
Name | Customer || Address | Pin
XYZ | Ghii | 23 | NY | 3001

As visible it's missing it's 3rd column.
While reading the data using spark.read.csv the df.columns is reading the first two column headers perfectly then taking the missing column as _C2.
Issue : It is automatically assigning numbers at the end of the following columns like
Address3 and Pin4 

How can I avoid getting numbers at the end of my header names
I tried reading the data from pandas and it takes the missing column as unknown_2 and follows up with proper column names after that.
Issue only persists while using spark.read method.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Welcome to SO! Sharing the actual code lines, even if very simple, as well as the 2 first lines of the resulting tables, would probably help the reader understand your issue faster. Check-out [ask] [mre].

You can read the csv using pandas and then convert it to a spark dataframe:
import pandas as pd

header = ['Name', 'Customer', 'Address', ...]
df = pd.read_csv(filename, header = None, names = header, skiprows=1)

# Pandas to Spark
df_sp = spark_session.createDataFrame(df_pd)

